# Proof of a result on infinite sums

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$\newcommand{\Wg}{\Omega}$
Let $\Wg$ be any set and $(a_x)_{x\in\Wg}$ be a family of real numbers indicised by $\Wg$. If $a_x\geq0$ for all $x\in\Wg$, we define:
$$\sum_{x\in\Wg}a_x=\sup\{a_1+a_2+\dotso+a_n:a_1,a_2,\dotsc,a_n\in\Wg\},$$
the supremum of finite sums. If the family has alternating signs, we consider $a_x^+,a_x^-$, the positive and negative parts. We define:
$$\sum_{x\in\Wg}a_x=\sum_{x\in\Wg}a_x^+-\sum_{x\in\Wg}a_x^-,$$
whenever either of these is finite, otherwise we say the family admits no sum. I have been then given a remark saying that if $\Wg$ is countable (i.e. there exists a bijection $f:\mathbb{N}\to\Wg$) and $a_x$ is a family which can be summed over $\Wg$, then for any such bijection $f$:
$$\sum_{x\in\Wg}a_x=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^na_{f(i)}.$$
I am trying to prove this. On the right side we have a limit of finite sums, which are all not over the left-hand side sum if the family is nonnegative, therefore for nonnegative families the limit, let us call it $L$, satisfies the following inequality with the sum, here denoted by $S$:
$$L\leq S.$$
How do I prove the converse? And how do I extend the result to families with alternating signs? In particular, how do I prove the existence of $S$ gives unconditional convergence to the series? I know the existence of $S$ guarantees absolute convergence to the series, but how do I prove that is equivalent to unconditional convergence? PS by absolute convergence I mean the convergence of the series of the absolute values, whereas by unconditional convergence I mean the convergence of any reordering to the same limit. I also admit infinite limits, still using the term "convergence", albeit maybe somewhat improper. Also, I'm not sure the tag is really appropriate, but I couldn't think of anything better than "(infinite) sum(s)" to search for and that gave "sequences-and-series" as best match to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For non-negative families $\{ a_x : x \in \Omega\}$ we get the converse inequality by noting that for every $K < S$, there is a finite subset $F_K \subset \Omega$ with

$$\sum_{x\in F_K} a_x > K,$$

as follows directly by the definition of $\sup$. Then we also have

$$K < \sum_{x\in F} a_x \leqslant S$$

for every finite $F$ with $F_K \subset F \subset \Omega$.

Now suppose $\Omega$ is countable, and $f\colon \mathbb{N}\to \Omega$ a bijection. Then $f^{-1}(F_K)$ is a finite subset of $\mathbb{N}$, so there is an $n_K$ with $f^{-1}(F_K) \subset \{i \in \mathbb{N} : i \leqslant n_K\}$. But that gives us

$$S \geqslant \sum_{i=1}^n a_{f(i)} \geqslant \sum_{i\in f^{-1}(F_K)} a_{f(i)} = \sum_{x\in F_K} a_x > K$$

for every $n \geqslant n_K$, and hence we have

$$K \leqslant \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{f(i)}$$

for every bijection $f\colon \mathbb{N}\to \Omega$. Since $K < S$ was chosen arbitrarily, it follows that

$$S = \sup \{ K : K < S\} \leqslant \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{f(i)}.$$

With the inequality in the other direction that you have already shown, we have equality (for every bijection $f\colon \mathbb{N}\to\Omega$).

If the family is not non-negative, let $\Omega^+ = \{x\in \Omega : a_x \geqslant 0\}$ and $\Omega^- = \Omega \setminus \Omega^+$. Assume first that

$$\sum_{x\in \Omega} \lvert a_x\rvert < +\infty.$$

Then to show that for every bijection $f\colon \mathbb{N}\to \Omega$ (if $\Omega$ is countable) we have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n a_{f(i)} = \underbrace{\sum_{x\in \Omega^+} a_x}_{P} + \underbrace{\sum_{x\in \Omega^-} a_x}_N,$$

we proceed much like above, only we consider two finite subsets, one of $\Omega^+$ and one of $\Omega^-$.

For every $\varepsilon > 0$ we choose finite subsets $A_\varepsilon \subset \Omega^+$ and $B_\varepsilon \subset \Omega^-$ with

$$\sum_{x\in A_\varepsilon} a_x > P - \varepsilon\quad\text{and} \quad\sum_{x\in B_\varepsilon} a_x < N + \varepsilon.$$

Then for every bijection $f\colon \mathbb{N}\to \Omega$, there is an $n(\varepsilon)$ such that

$$f^{-1}(A_\varepsilon\cup B_\varepsilon) \subset \{i \in \mathbb{N} : i \leqslant n(\varepsilon)\}.$$

Thus, for $n \geqslant n(\varepsilon)$ we have

$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_{f(i)} = \underbrace{\sum_{x\in A_\varepsilon} a_x + \sum_{x\in A^{(n)}} a_x}_{\in (P-\varepsilon,P]} + \underbrace{\sum_{x\in B_\varepsilon} a_x + \sum_{x\in B^{(n)}} a_x}_{\in [N, N+\varepsilon)},$$

where $A^{(n)} = \{x\in \Omega^+\setminus A_\varepsilon : f^{-1}(x) \leqslant n\}$ and $B^{(n)} = \{ x\in \Omega^- \setminus B_\varepsilon : f^{-1}(x) \leqslant n\}$, and it follows that

$$P-\varepsilon + N < \sum_{i=1}^n a_{f(i)} < P + N + \varepsilon$$

for all $n \geqslant n(\varepsilon)$. The arbitrariness of $\varepsilon > 0$ shows

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n a_{f(i)} = P + N$$

for every bijection $f\colon \mathbb{N}\to\Omega$ as desired.

If $\sum\limits_{x\in \Omega^+} a_x = +\infty$ or $\sum\limits_{x\in \Omega^-} a_x = -\infty$, but not both, then we again need only consider one finite subset of $\Omega^+$ resp. $\Omega^-$. Suppose $P = +\infty$ and $N > -\infty$. Then for every $K < +\infty$, choose a finite $A_K \subset \Omega^+$ with $\sum\limits_{x\in A_K} a_x > K$, then like above we see that

$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_{f(i)} > K + N$$

for all large enough $n$, whence

$$\liminf_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n a_{f(i)} \geqslant K+N.$$

Since $K < +\infty$ was arbitrary,

$$\liminf_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n a_{f(i)} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n a_{f(i)} = +\infty.$$

The case $P < +\infty$ and $N = -\infty$ is similar.

So we have seen that if at least one of $\sum a_x^+$ and $\sum a_x^-$ is finite, then the series

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{f(i)}\tag{s}$$

is unconditionally convergent in the extended sense allowing $\pm\infty$ as limits.

To complete it, we need to show that if the series $(\mathrm{s})$ is unconditionally convergent in the extended sense, then $\sum a_x^+ < +\infty$ or $\sum a_x^- < +\infty$. We prove the contrapositive, and show that if $\sum a_x^+ = \sum a_x^- = +\infty$, then there are bijections $f_1,f_2 \colon \mathbb{N}\to \Omega$ with

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n a_{f_1(i)} = + \infty\quad \text{and}\quad \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n a_{f_2(i)} = -\infty.$$

Note that there need not exist any bijection for which the series is (conditionally) convergent.

Choose bijections $g\colon \mathbb{N} \to \Omega^+$ and $h\colon \mathbb{N} \to \Omega^-$. Let $p_0 = q_0 = 0$ and define recursively

$$\begin{gathered}
p_n := \min \left\{ p \in \mathbb{N} : p > p_{n-1}\text{ and } \sum_{i=p_{n-1}+1}^p a_{g(i)} \geqslant 1 + \lvert a_{h(n)}\rvert\right\},\\
q_n := \min \left\{ q\in \mathbb{N} : q > q_{n-1}\text{ and } \sum_{i=q_{n-1}+1}^q \lvert a_{h(i)}\rvert \geqslant 1 + a_{g(n)}\right\}.
\end{gathered}$$

Then let

$$f_1(i) = \begin{cases} h(n) &, i = p_n + n\\ g(i -n) &, p_n+n < i < p_{n+1}+n+1\end{cases}$$

and

$$f_2(i) = \begin{cases} g(n) &, i = q_n + n\\ h(i-n) &, q_n + n < i < q_{n+1} + n+1.\end{cases}$$

We show that $f_1\colon \mathbb{N} \to \Omega$ is a bijection, the proof for $f_2$ is analogous. The map

$$\begin{gathered}
\beta \colon \mathbb{N}\times \{0,1\} \to \mathbb{N}\\
\beta(i,0) = i + \min \{ k \in \mathbb{N} : i \leqslant p_k\} - 1\\
\beta(i,1) = p_i + i
\end{gathered}$$

is a bijection: $\beta$ is strictly monotonic on $\mathbb{N}\times \{0\}$ and on $\mathbb{N}\times \{1\}$, and if $p_{k-1} < i \leqslant p_k$, then $\beta(k-1,1) = p_{k-1} + k-1 < \beta(i,0) = i+k-1 \leqslant p_k + k-1 < p_k + k = \beta(k,1)$, so we have $\beta(i,0) \neq \beta(k,1)$ for all $i,k\in\mathbb{N}$, which shows the injectivity. Since the sequence $p_n + n$ is strictly increasing, for every $j\in \mathbb{N}$ there is exactly one $k\in \mathbb{N}$ with $p_{k-1} + k-1 < j \leqslant p_k+k$ (with $p_0 = 0$), and $j = \beta(k,1)$ if $j = p_k+k$, while $j = \beta(j+1-k,0)$ if $j < p_k+k$.

$K\colon \mathbb{N}\times \{0,1\} \to \Omega;\, K(i,0) = g(i);\, K(i,1) = h(i)$ is a bijection since $g$ is a bijection $\mathbb{N}\to \Omega^+$ and $h$ a bijection $\mathbb{N}\to \Omega^-$, and $\Omega = \Omega^+ \cup \Omega^-$ is a disjoint union. Thus $f_1 = K\circ \beta^{-1}$ is a bijection $\mathbb{N}\to \Omega$.

One verifies that

$$\sum_{i=1}^k a_{f_1(i)} \geqslant n$$

for all $k \geqslant p_n + n$ and

$$\sum_{i=1}^k a_{f_2(i)} \leqslant -n$$

for all $k \geqslant q_n + n$.

We prove only the former, the latter is again analogous.

For any $k\in \mathbb{N}$, there is a unique $n$ such that $p_n + n \leqslant k < p_{n+1} + n+1$. Then

$$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=1}^k a_{f_1(i)} &= \sum_{j=1}^n \left(\biggl(\sum_{i=p_{j-1}+j}^{p_j+j-1} a_{f_1(i)}\biggr) + a_{f_1(p_j+j)}\right) + \sum_{i=p_n+n+1}^k a_{f_1(i)}\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^n \Biggl(\biggl( \underbrace{\sum_{m=p_{j-1}+1}^{p_j} a_{g(m)}}_{\geqslant 1 + \lvert a_{h(j)}\rvert}\biggr) + a_{h(j)}\Biggr) + \underbrace{\sum_{m = p_n+1}^{k-n} a_{g(m)}}_{\geqslant 0}\\
&\geqslant \sum_{j=1}^n 1 = n.
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Side note: in $P+N-\epsilon<\text{that sum}<P+N+\epsilon$, I think you want loose inequalities :).

Comment: That wouldn't change anything, but it's not necessary. I have chosen the sets so that the sum of the positive terms (with index $\leqslant n$) is $> P-\varepsilon$, and the sum of the negative terms is $< N+\varepsilon$, that gives us the strict inequalities, since if we add more terms, the sum of the negative terms can only become smaller [and the sum of positive terms is always $\leqslant P$], and the sum of positive terms can only become larger [and the sum of negative terms is always $\geqslant N$] if we add more terms to the sum.

Comment: yes, I was just thinking that the inequality was becoming loose, but that is because inequalities always become loose when passing to the limit :).

To make it explicit, $f_1,f_2$ are injective because if $f_1(i)=f_1(j)$ the definitions used must be the same for both since $g$ has values in $\Omega^+$ and $h$ in $\Omega^-$ which are disjoint, and $g,h$ are bijections. Similarly for $f_2$. I can't put my finger on why they are surjective though.

Comment: I'd also like to see how to verify one of the last two inequalities, say the first one. I guess the other one would be similar.

Comment: They are surjective because every $g(k)$ and every $h(k)$ is used, and $\Omega = g(\mathbb{N}) \cup h(\mathbb{N})$. I'll expand the answer, since an elaboration wouldn't fit in the comment character limit. It will take a bit, however, I'm not a fast typist.

Comment: Okay, added proofs for the last things (one case each).